# DB2 UDF to return added date?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, user-defined-functions, ibm-midrange

I am trying to make a DB2 UDF that takes input a date and returns new date with some months added to it. The query syntax for this step is to use

```
 select date + 12 months from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Inside the UDF I can't get this to work

```
monthsToAdd INTEGER;
SET monthsToAdd=4;
set result= inputDate + monthsToAdd + MONTHS;
return result;
```

It says

> SQL State: 42816
>   Vendor Code: -182
>   Message: [SQL0182] A date, time, or timestamp expression not valid. Cause . . . . . :   One of the following has occurred: -- An operand of addition is a date and the other is not a date duration. -- An operand of addition is a time and the other is not a time duration. -- An operand of addition is a timestamp and the other is not a duration. -- An operand of subtraction is a date and the other is not a date, character, or date duration. -- An operand of subtraction is a time and the other is not a time, character, or time duration. -- An operand of subtraction is a timestamp and the other is not a timestamp, character, or duration. Recovery  . . . :   Correct the arithmetic expression so that it contains a valid date, time, or timestamp expression. Try the request again.

Comment: Is the error a compile-time error (Can you create the procedure?) or a run-time error? Could you post the entire Create Procedure stmt?

Comment: Any reason not to just use the DB2 scalar function ADD_MONTHS, available since DB2 for IBM i 6.1, of Jan-2008; perhaps still on v5r4 at the time? For reference: more recent release doc at [IBM i 7.2->Database->Reference->SQL reference->Built-in functions->Scalar functions->ADD_MONTHS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaaddmonths.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple fix:

```
set result = inputDate + monthsToAdd MONTHS;
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, I tried that earlier but it won't work it says 'End of statement missing '

Comment: @ZoHas Then perhaps, just omit the `SET` and declarative for `RESULT`, and simply code `RETURN inputDate + monthsToAdd MONTHS`  NB, the lack of a semicolon

Answer (score 1):

As actually scripted on a v5r3 DB2 for i5/OS [and also with DB2 for IBM i 7.3]:

```
create function add_months             
( inputDate   DATE                     
, monthsToAdd INTEGER                  
) returns DATE                         
language SQL DETERMINISTIC             
  RETURN inputDate + monthsToAdd MONTHS

select add_months(date'2016-04-12', 6)
from sysibm.sysdummy1
-- likeness of a report from above query follows:
ADD_MONTHS
2016-10-12
```

Comment: Note: The ADD_MONTHS name was chosen in the above so unqualified references would end up using the system-supplied scalar function for new queries or re-created VIEWs when available; i.e. presuming the creation and use starts with a release prior to IBM i 6.1, with which the DB2 for i first provides that scalar.